# How to specify a label "weight" in GeoServer SLD to control label priority?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, sld

I'm labelling a cities layer using GeoServer SLD. I need the larger city labels to draw first, then the smaller city labels to draw if there is enough room. There is a `pop_band` field which I'm using to distinguish between large and small cities.

In ArcMap this would be achieved by assigning a higher *weight* (or importance) to the larger city label class. Does this concept exist in GeoServer using SLD?

For example, the large cities like Sydney and Brisbane (in grey) should be labelled here before labelling the smaller cities like Toowoomba and Wollongong:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the relevant SLD:

```
<Rule>
  <Name>LargePop</Name>
  <Title>Large cities</Title>
  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
      <ogc:PropertyName>pop_band</ogc:PropertyName>
      <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
      <Mark>
        <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#727272</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </Mark>
      <Size>18</Size>
    </Graphic>
  </PointSymbolizer>
  <TextSymbolizer>
 <Label>
   <ogc:PropertyName>town_name</ogc:PropertyName>
 </Label>
 <Font>
   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
   <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
   <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
   <CssParameter name="font-weight">bold</CssParameter>
 </Font>
 <LabelPlacement>
   <PointPlacement>
     <AnchorPoint>
       <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
       <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
     </AnchorPoint>
   </PointPlacement>
 </LabelPlacement>
 <Fill>
   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
 </Fill>
</TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>
<Rule>
  <Name>MediumPop</Name>
  <Title>Medium cities</Title>
  <ogc:Filter>
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>pop_band</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>pop_band</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
  <PointSymbolizer>
    <Graphic>
      <Mark>
        <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#0033CC</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </Mark>
      <Size>12</Size>
    </Graphic>
  </PointSymbolizer>
  <TextSymbolizer>
 <Label>
   <ogc:PropertyName>town_name</ogc:PropertyName>
 </Label>
 <Font>
   <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
   <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
   <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
 </Font>
 <LabelPlacement>
   <PointPlacement>
     <AnchorPoint>
       <AnchorPointX>0.5</AnchorPointX>
       <AnchorPointY>0.0</AnchorPointY>
     </AnchorPoint>
   </PointPlacement>
 </LabelPlacement>
 <Fill>
   <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
 </Fill>
</TextSymbolizer>
</Rule>
```

I'm aware that I can use `<MaxScaleDenominator>` to control whether the smaller cities draw at all, but this doesn't address the issue here since it doesn't assign a greater importance to the larger city label layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a [`priority`](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#priority-labeling) to the labels.

So add something like if you have an attribute to proxy priority:

```
<Priority>
    <ogc:PropertyName>population</ogc:PropertyName>
</Priority>
```

to your `TextSymbolizer`. Or, in your case you could just use a literal value for the 2 levels.

Comment: Does it matter where in the `TextSymbolizer` I place this - your answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78939/3112 suggests it does? I tried starting afresh with the simple [point with default label SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/_downloads/point_pointwithdefaultlabel.sld) (which works) then adding the `Priority` lines as above (noting that there is a valid `population` field on the layer). This fails with `line 27: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'PropertyName'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":expression}' is expected.`

Comment: it should probably be ogc:PropertyName

Comment: Thanks again. Does this mean that the documentation at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#priority-labeling is out of date?

Comment: no, just wrong - I'll fix it.