# Why does GeoServer SLD sometimes fail when copy/pasting sample code?

Tags: geoserver, symbology, sld

Sometimes I find that GeoServer SLD files fail to validate, even when copying code directly from the [SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/index.html).

For example, I start with the [polygon with styled label](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/polygons.html#polygon-with-styled-label) sample code, paste it into a new GeoServer style, validate it, and confirm that everything is fine.

Next I try to add the [label halo](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/polygons.html#label-halo) code:

```
<Halo>
  <Radius>3</Radius>
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
</Halo>
```

I can see that the `halo` is located just before the closing `</TextSymbolizer>` in the SLD Cookbook example, so I paste it just before the `</TextSymbolizer>` in my style:

```
  <Fill>
    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
  </Fill>
  <Halo>
    <Radius>3</Radius>
    <Fill>
      <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter> 
    </Fill>
  </Halo>
</TextSymbolizer>
```

This now fails to validate with the message:

> line 41: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting
>   with element 'Halo'. One of
>   '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":VendorOption}' is expected.

This error message doesn't really help me. What is the cause of this problem and how can it be rectified?

Comment: we welcome documentation updates from users - http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/docguide/contributing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I stumbled across the answer to this (I can't see it explicitly listed in the GeoServer documentation) so I'm posting it here in case it helps others.*

Ian Turton mentions in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78939/3112) that:

> XML is ordered (at least in the [SLD schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd)) so you must use the
>   elements in the right order

Examining the [SLD schema](http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd) and searching for the keyword `halo`, it's apparent that the halo must be specified *before* the `fill`:

```
<xsd:element ref="sld:Halo" minOccurs="0"/>
<xsd:element ref="sld:Fill" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Re-ordering the elements in my SLD to match this pattern resolves the problem.

The key point is that, as Ian mentions, the order of elements in a GeoServer SLD file is important.

Comment: SLD is an OGC standard and requirement of correctly ordered elements is set there, not by GeoServer.